# Split-View application, how to change header for popover?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got a split-view application. When in Portrait orientation, there is a popover, it has a title "Root View Controller", how can I change it? moreover, how to skip popover when I select a cell? thanks. Here is the screenshot:
[image: How to change the Root View Controller title?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the view controller that will be the master view in the UISplitViewController and set the title in the viewDidLoad method like this:

```
self.title = @"Set Title";
```

Since the master view will eventually modify the detail view you can place a method in the detail view controller to dismiss the UIPopoverController after you select a row.  Below is an example.

So in DetailViewController(Detail View) implement a method like this

```
    - (void)setDetailDescription:(NSString *)text {

    // Put code to update the detail view here

    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

}
```

And then in your RootViewController(Master View) implement this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
DetailViewController *dc = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

[dc setDescription:@"Update detail view"];
```

}

Take note that your setup will vary so you will have to adapt this code to your project.

Answer (score 3):

in the ViewController set

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"The text you want";
```

and to "skip" the popover when a row is selected do sometime like this

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```